# Javascript drop-down menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a site redesign and something's wrong with my CSS/javascript and I can't get the drop down menus to pop up.  I made a mistake typing the JS, the JS on there now is what won't work.

CSS

```
#menu {
font-size:large;
margin:0;
padding:0 0 0 .5em;
list-style:none;
width:100%;
text-align:left;
}


#menu ul, #menu li {
padding:0 0 0 2em;
background-color:gray;
width:auto;
border-bottom:1 gray solid;
}

/*LI display inline */
#menu li {
float:left;
background:white;
position:relative;
list-style:none;
margin:0 0 0 0;
text-align:center;

}

/*parent menu*/
#menu li a {
display:block;
padding:0 0 0 0;
height:40px;
font-weight:200;
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
color:black;
border:1 1 1 1;
}

#menu li a:hover {
color:#eeeeee;
text-align:center;
}

/* style for default selected value */ 
#menu a.selected {
color:#6699FF;
}
/* submenu */ 
#menu ul {
position:absolute;
display:none;
margin:0 0 0 -1px;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
text-align:center;
}

#menu ul {
left: 0;
}
#menu ul ul {
top: -1px;
background:0063dc;
text-align:center;
color:black;
font-weight:200;
text-align:center;
}

#menu ul li {
/*overflow:hidden;*/
border-top:1px solid #eeeeee;
height:25px;
margin:0 0 0 -1px;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
position: relative;
}

#menu ul a {
display:block;
color:white;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

JS

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#menu ul").hover(
    function () {
    $(this).children("li").css({zIndex:90}).fadeIn(250);
    },function(){
    $(this).children("li").fadeOut(250);
});//hover
```

});
HTML

```
 <input type="hidden" name="arav" />
                    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MEMBERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FACTS</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EDUCATION</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">RESEARCH</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>



</ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to select by writing `$('#nav li')`? There is no wrapping element of `#nav`. Also the `li`s won't have children of type `ul` as you are trying to select.

Comment: What are expecting to pop up? What is the parent and whom are the children? All I see are parent items and your code only reflects a hover effect that fades the item.

Comment: put complete html code if there is one

Answer (score 3):

you are missing `#nav` instead you have `#menu`.

Change `#nav` to `#menu` in the javascript code or change the `id="menu"` to `id="nav"` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you your  and then your JavaScript as $('#nav not menu :)
That may be it, try that and let me know how you get on

UPDATE

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu li").hover(function () {
      $(this).fadeIn(250);
    },function(){
      $(this).fadeIut(250);
    });//hover

});// document ready
```

Because you have already chose to use #menu li in the jquery, there is no need to use this).children.  This way is a lot more practical.  Also just set the z-index in your CSS file.

Comment: Yeah I do need to set the z-index in the CSS.  That was an IE fix because the animation looked funky in IE without doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu ul").hover(
        function () {
        $(this).children("li").css({zIndex:90}).fadeIn(250);
        },function(){
        $(this).children("li").fadeOut(250);
    });//hover

});
```

Comment: I tried that before and it's not working either :/

Comment: li is the child of ul. in your code you were considering ul as the child of li

Comment: In the case of this dropdown, `ul` **is** the child of `li` - because you want to target the second level `ul`.

Comment: There is an example of the code in my answer that removes the use of children,  which isn't needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
$("#nav li").hover(
```

to

```
$("#menu li").hover(
```